# insert row before the first row

Tags: mysql, netbeans, derby

I'm trying to write to a database at the beginning so that the new row is the first row.The code i have here will write to it, but it won't start before the first row. I've tried using resultset and tried to use beforeFirst(), but it tells me that i can't use either one. I'm stumped as to how to do it. any help would be appreciated! :D

```
        String host = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Scores";
        String uName = "root";
        String uPass= "root";

         Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection( host, uName, uPass );                      
         String SQLw = "INSERT into ROOT.HISCORES (Intials,Score) values (?,?)";


         pst = con.prepareStatement(SQLw);

         pst.setString(1,jtxtIntials.getText());
         pst.setString(2,Score);



         pst.execute();
```

Comment: There is no order to rows in a database, other than that imposed by `ORDER BY` when you perform a query.

Comment: Exactly as @Barmar says.   However, you can always set the primary key for your row to a low value (if it is not already taken) so you can create a index with which to do your order by.  If there is no space, you can create an orderBy key and use this for your ordering

Comment: and yet, i'm able to delete the last row in my database and it actually be the last one without even calling order by.

Comment: coincidence. there is no concept of first or last.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rows in a relational database are indeed stored in some physical order, but using SQL, you are unable to control this order directly. Thinking of the order in which the rows are physically stored is absolutely against the philosophy of SQL, and hence such a functionality is not included in it.

If you are interested in ordering your rows, you should add an extra attribute, for numbering the rows, by example, and use the `ORDER BY` clause whenever retrieving them, as mentioned in the comments.

Comment: my original intention was to create a recent score. where it was just a bunch of random scores. but the recent scores wasn't working. It wouldn't insert a score at the top. but using BY ORDER, i can delete the lowest score. By doing that i can insert a new score that will made at the bottom of the database. It won't get deleted so long as the new score isn't the lowest. then i use BY ORDER again to read it in a descending order, making a hi score board! For it to work correctly though it has to write first, then delete, and finally read.

This literally took me 4 hours to figure out. Q_Q